# blank screen after updating 16.04.3LTS

Tags: updates, screen

Did a clean install 16.04.3lts on a Lenovo T60.
After updating and restart.
It goes to blank screen.

Not sure what to do next

Comment: Here's a very good resource to help troubleshoot your issue: https://askubuntu.com/q/162075/32664. Please report back what you've discovered in your research.

Comment: FIXED with grub customizer to remove updated linux 4.13.    Then gedit grub GRUB_DEFAULT=0 to GRUB_DEFAULT=1